# Connecting Microcontroller to Higher potential

Tags: microcontroller, design, input-impedance

I am curious how to determine what voltage is acceptable to connect to a micro-controller through a resistor.

From the data sheet the highest voltage on a GPIO is 3.8V.

So If I have 5 Volts going through a.... lets say 1M resistor to the 3.3V input pin is this ok?

Clearly there is a internal resistor and some voltage drop will occur, but the datasheet does not seem to come out and say it.

I haven't found the internal resistor for the micro-controller so I am curious if I am looking for the correct value...

I am using the CC3200 from TI

Comment: The 3.3V input pin is not a GPIO pin.

Comment: I meant a input GPIO pin not the power pin

Comment: Does the datasheet mention a maximum over-voltage current on the input pin?

Comment: In the real world, it will probably be OK. Most likely the GPIO pin has a diode from input to VCC. This diode will forward bias, but the 1M resistor will limit the current so that it will not hurt anything. Sometimes datasheets specify maximum current to cover this kind of situation. If you need to be sure whether it is OK, ask TI. Or, you can devise some way to avoid the situation.

Comment: So it might not be included in the data-sheet...

Comment: No mention of Max current for current sink on GPIO... there is a min value.

Comment: You're much better off using two resistors to explicitly create a voltage divider than to depend on the internal characteristics of the chip's input circuitry.

Comment: Doxy, I am curious... I probably wont implement it in the design, but I would like to know the answer still!

Comment: Summary: If the IC is operating mis-operation MAY occur.

Comment: ANY situation that pulls a pin above its absolute maximum rating (voltage or current) means that the manufacturer no longer guarantees that the chip will ever behave in a predictable way for the rest of its life.  Reliable design means never doing this.

Answer (score 1):

> From the data sheet the highest voltage on a GPIO is 3.8V.
>
> So If I have 5 Volts going through a.... lets say 1M resistor to the 3.3V input pin is this ok?

The datasheet DOES explicitly cover the situation by stating an absolute maximum voltage.   Above that voltage damage MAY occur.

If the IC is operating mis-operation may occur. Or may not.

Not every "might happen" can be covered or identified.
While 1 megOhm will usually be safe there are no guarantees.

**Contrived but possible example:**
An internal diode structure is reverse biased
**and** a usually inaccessible node is trickled up at a few uA
**until** an internal parasitic SCR structure is triggered.
This latches on and shorts VCC into some_place-it_ought_not_be
and destroys the IC.

Can happen. Has happened. Can never be sure.
Modern IC designs specifically try to avoid the creation of parasitic SCRs that   traditionally caused IC latchup and destruction. Murphy can still outsmart them on occasion.

Comment: I agree, EXCEPT, I would simply ask TI if it is OK. They may know, and may answer. Then again, if you are a low production run customer, maybe they won't care enough to give you the time of day.

Comment: Consider a 5V trace running near a GPIO pin that is pulled low... How close can I get this trace to the GPIO pin?..,This sparked my interest in the question...I just wanted to make sure there was not some other name that was not obvious to me.

Comment: @mkeith For TI to know the answer they would need to know the question :-). ie the standard conditions are well defined and are designed to stop parasitic diodes etc conducting. Once this starts the chip can have many possible undesigned features activated. As these occur across devices which exist by accident, characterising all possible ones is  an immense task. It's easier to protect inputs so they never go into illegal states than to determine what happens if you do.

Comment: @tman Trace to pin clearances with both at low voltage will be set by PCB design-rule rules which are set to guarantee that fabrication is reliable. At low voltages and in normal situations these clearances will be adequate to eliminate secondary effects. Abnormal situations may be high humidity  or board contamination or eg RF or very high impedance circuits. Things like "guard rings" may be  needed when normal adjacent signals affect ultra sensitive or very high Z circuits.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, the question is reasonably clear. "Can I put a 1M pullup to 5V on this pin." I guess my perspective is that if it saves me a transistor, I might propose to do it, but only if it is a high volume design and only if TI will bless it. Or you could try it and check. (5-3.8)/1M = 1.2 uA. Maybe 1.2 uA is not enough to get to 3.8V?

Comment: @Mkeith if it was a specific circuit and you could define all the conditions and if you were specific about what die shrink version you were using then TI may be prepared to take your money to look at the actual silicon design and give you a probably non binding assessment. If it saved you a transistor to do it then you'd probably want to be making a million+ per year to justify it. A transistor in this context probably costs comfortably under 1 cent and board area and placement come to several times that. Designing to within spec will usually [tm] be preferred.

Comment: Yes, the boards I design run several hundred K per year. One popular product may have hit 1 million per year. I agree that eliminating a transistor only makes sense in that context. Yes, SOT-23 BJT costs around 0.75 cents. My company has a good relationship with TI, and normally they reply to specific technical questions without any problem. I do not know how they treat hobbyists and low volume customers. 15 years ago, TI, national, linear, maxim all provided decent support for all comers. Not sure nowadays.